# PHP move_uploaded_file() only moves the last picture to the folder

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form though which i want to upload multiple images and store them in my folder, but my program only stores the last selected image.

My form:

```
<form method="POST" action="server.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple>
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="add">ADD</button>
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
$images = $_FILES['pictures'];
$image_names = $images['name'];
$image_tmpnames = $images['tmp_name'];

foreach($image_names as $image_name){

  $foto = 'images/' . $image_name;

  foreach($image_tmpnames as $image_tmpname){
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmpname,$foto);
      }
}
```

How can I fix this so all of the pictures will be moved to my "images" folder?

Comment: Think about it… for every *image name*, you move **all** the *temp names* to that image name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try other loop, and set the distination path.

I craft this code you can implement in your solution:

```
$arquivo = isset($_FILES['img']) ? $_FILES['img'] : FALSE;
for ($controle = 0; $controle < count($arquivo['name']); $controle++){
    $destino = $diretorio."/".$arquivo['name'][$controle];
    if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$controle], $destino)){
        echo "Upload sucess<br>"; 
    }else{
        echo "Erro upload";
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use nested loops. You want to process the two arrays in parallel, not as a cross-product.

```
foreach ($image_names as $i => $image_name) {
    $image_tmpname = $image_tmpnames[$i];
    $foto = 'images/' . $image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmpname,$foto);
}
```